# UNIQUE constraint where NULL is one valid value

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Inn PostgreSQL I want to have a multi-column UNIQUE constraint where one of the columns can be NULL exactly once.

What I've tried so far:

```
ALTER TABLE customexternalemail 
ADD CONSTRAINT customexternalemail_sp_emaildomain_unique 
    UNIQUE(serviceproviderid, emailprefix, emaildomainid);
```

Where `serviceproviderid` and `emaildomainid` are BIGINT, and `emailprefix` is TEXT. `emaildomainid` is the only column with NULL allowed, and is the column I'm having trouble with.

Basically, I want to allow only one entry matching a combination of `serviceproviderid`, `emailprefix`, and `emaildomainid`, where `emaildomainid` could be a BIGINT value or NULL. Currently (with the above constraint), it will accept repeats if `emaildomainid` is NULL, but if `emaildomainid` is not NULL, it must be unique.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create two [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html). They are supported since [version 7.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-7-2.html#AEN153667), which was released in February 2002.

This one will check that any combinaison of the three columns will be unique when `emaildomainid` isn't null:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customexternalemail_sp_emaildomain_unique_not_null 
    ON customexternalemail (serviceproviderid, emailprefix, emaildomainid)
    WHERE emaildomainid IS NOT NULL;
```

This one will ensure that for any row which has a null value for `emaildomainid`, the combination `(serviceproviderid, emailprefix)` will be unique:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customexternalemail_sp_emaildomain_unique_null 
    ON customexternalemail (serviceproviderid, emailprefix)
    WHERE emaildomainid IS NULL;
```